# Advices to create a command line text editor in .NET

Tags: .net, windows, command-line, text-editor

I want to create a command line text editor with .Net.

I always do GUI applications so I'm a little lost about whole deal with this task. One of the first things I need to know is how create an scrollable editor area. A place where I can write whatever I want and move upwards and downwards. Maybe there exist a ready to use framework that I haven't found. So for this reason I'm asking for advices.

Another thing is how do I create a menu bar that don't move with the editor area when scrolling.

To summarize I want to create a very simple editor like EDIT for the windows console.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What do you hope to accomplish that a normal window-based one wouldn't do 100x better?

Comment: @LasseV.karlsen i want to create a CUA text editor, that runs in commandline to do things remotely where i don't have GUI access. There are thousands of good editors but the mayority of commandline editors are not CUA compatible and if they are, they are deprecated. The goal is to keep it simple, emacs for example has an CUA mode but i dont like the way it work and is a lot more than a text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what CUA means, but...
you can use Console.SetCursorPosition() to set the position of the cursor to allow writes wherever you need.

example:

```
public void Run()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World.");
    Console.WriteLine("buffer size: (w,h)= ({0},{1})", Console.BufferWidth, Console.BufferHeight);
    Console.WriteLine("position= ({0},{1})", Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, again.");
    Console.WriteLine("position= ({0},{1})", Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop);
    int x= 2000;
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nCounting to {0}...", x);
    int left= Console.CursorLeft;
    int top= Console.CursorTop;
    for (int i= 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
        Console.Write("{0,6}",i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\ndone.");
}
```

Given that capability, you could then build up more powerful widgets, like a menu bar, a command bar, and so on.

I don't know of a way to "read" text at a given position in the console using only managed code; you can do it via pInvoke. You'll need to read from the screen in order to support cut/paste operations, searches, and so on. Even with the pInvoke possibility, I'd suggest a double-buffering write approach, where you maintain a cache in your managed code of what you've written to the screen.  Something like this:

http://code.google.com/p/console-forms/source/browse/trunk/Console.Forms/Console.Forms/Drawing/ConsoleCanvas.cs?spec=svn9&r=9

Then when you need to read from the "console", just read from your buffer. This avoids crossing the pInvoke threshold, which is expensive, for each read.

With these ingredients, you have the basic building blocks of a console-mode editor.

Comment: interesting answer, im seeing right now the proyect home site. One of the purpose behind the creation of Console.Form was to recreate Edit.exe, i.e. the same thing i want to do, :). i'm going to play with the code and see what emerges